# How can I disable screen blanking without /etc /X11/xorg.conf on Nvidia Optimus laptop

Tags: xorg, screen, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit, kernel Linux 3.5.0-39-generic, on a system that has an Nvidia GE Force GT 640m / Intel HD graphics 4000 - 1.0 GB graphics processor assembly. In order to get the unity 3d desktop features to work correctly I needed to install bumblebee. The problem this has created is that in order for the desktop effects to work with Optimus laptops you must remove /etc/X11/xorg.conf . If using an Optimus laptop unity 3d will not work until this file is removed after this file has been removed if you replace it the desktop will load into a black screen. The reason I want this file is because without it's having a server layout section containing Option "BlankTime" "0", Option "StandbyTime" "0", Option "SuspendTime" "0", Option "OffTime" "0" my desktop goes blank every 10 minutes this is very  frustrating when attempting to intake media.

This is the relevant data from `xset -q`

Screen Saver:

```
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes

  timeout:  600    cycle:  600

DPMS (Energy Star):

  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0

  DPMS is Enabled
```

if anyone would present me with a solution to this that doesn't involve something as inelegant as installing caffeine or writing a script to move the cursor every so often. my satisfaction would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just an ArchLinux user passing through, but I think you can get the desired effect by running:

```
xset s off
```

after X has started.

`xset` lets you set many of the same options xorg.conf controls dynamically after X has started. The `xset s` options all control settings related to the screensaver. See the `xset` man page for a list of all the various `s` options, but `xset s off` should disable the screensaver completely. You can run `xset q` again to see what settings have been changed. Without Xorg.conf files, I think `xset` is your best bet for changing those options.

I'm not sure of the best way to automate `xset` being run in Ubuntu - possibly you could add it to your `~/.xinitrc` file, or maybe a more experienced Ubuntu user can chime in with the canonical way to run commands when the desktop environment starts.

Technically these various options for automatically running commands are "scripts", but I think you'll agree `xset s off` is a pretty short one.